# Why does testing float for null produce compilation error ”invalid operands to binary == (have 'float' and 'void *')”?

Tags: c, void, operands

```
    scanf("%f", &lista2.pret);
    fflush(stdin);

    if (lista2.pret == NULL ) goto eror2; // error

    fseek(o,(nn-1)*sizeof(lista2),SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&lista2,sizeof(lista2),1,o);

    break;
  }

  fclose(o);
  break;
}
```

Error:

```
[Error] invalid operands to binary == (have 'float' and 'void *')`
```

What is wrong?

Comment: A `float` can never be `NULL`. This is an invalid comparison.

Comment: `lista2.pret == NULL` is invalid, that's what's wrong. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: How is `pret` defined?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: A `float` can compare equal to `NULL`. Per the C standard, `NULL` is a *null pointer constant*, and a null pointer constant is either an integer constant expression with value 0 or such an expression cast to `void *`. If a C implementation chooses the former, then `lista2.pret == NULL` is a valid expression, in which the integer zero will be converted to `float`. So there are more concepts at play than merely ”`NULL` is not for `float`.”

Comment: @melpomene: Whether `lista2.pret == NULL` is invalid is implementation-dependent, per my comment above.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'd argue that it's always semantically nonsense (because `NULL` is meant for pointers). However, we also know that it's invalid on the implementation OP uses because the error message says so.

Comment: @melpomene: Yes, it is always an error in practice. But you cannot expect learners to have the background knowledge to know that. When teaching, (a) things that experts assume have to be stated explicitly, and (b) the statements teachers make ought to be actually true. Stating that `lista2.pret == NULL` is invalid because it is wrong in our heads (but not always truly invalid in the compiler-accepted-source-code sense) can actually mislead people who do not have the same context in their heads and may go on with wrong information in their heads that later leads to wrong conclusions.

Answer (score 2):

There is a *constraint* on the `==` operator such that:

— both operands have arithmetic type;

— both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;

— one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of `void`; or

— one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant.

`lista2.pret` is obviously a floating point (arithmetic) type, so it cannot be compared to `NULL`.  Only pointer types can be compared to `NULL`.

Comment: This answers technically. However, if we look at the code, why would somebody compare a `float` to `NULL`? To people knowledgeable in C, that makes no sense, because they are different and are intended to be disparate. The fact that it is just after a `scanf` is a clue. The author appears to be attempting to discern whether a `float` was successfully obtained. This makes sense in some programming languages; some other programming languages have *null* placeholders to indicate a value is not present. Thus, the true question the OP is asking may be: “Why didn’t my test for scanf success work?”

Answer (score 0):

To test whether `scanf` successfully scanned a `float` in this situation, you should use:

```
if (1 != scanf("%f", &lista2.pret))
    goto ero2;
```

The `float` type does not use `NULL` to indicate there is no value. `NULL` is used with pointers that way—a pointer can have either the address of an actual object or can have the “value” `NULL`. However, unlike some other languages, C does not generally have a null value that indicates an object is not holding a valid value. `NULL` is intended for use just with pointers, not with integers, floating-point values, or other types of objects.

The floating-point type actually does have a “value” to indicate the object is not holding a number. It is called a NaN, for Not a Number, and is `NAN` in source code after including `<math.h>`. You could test whether `lista2.pret` is a NaN. However, since NaNs are not numbers, they cannot be equal to anything, so you would not test with `lista2.pret == NAN`. Instead, you would use `isnan(lista2.pret)`.

However, `scanf` does not indicate failure by putting a NaN in a `float`. `scanf` indicates failure by its return value. It returns the number of conversions it successfully performed. So, when using `scanf(%f, &lista2.pret)` to convert some input to a `float`, the result will be 0 or 1 to indicate 0 or 1 successful conversions. It may also be `EOF` to indicate some input failure occurred. So, to test whether `scanf` successfully scanned a `float`, compare its return value to 1.

(Incidentally, you should know that `fflush(stdin)` is an extension to the base C language that is implementation dependent. You are likely using Microsoft Windows. On other C implementations, `fflush(stdin)` may not work the same way and could break your program.)